# Android Disable focusable of keyboard of CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, keyboard, android-edittext

I have an EditText with a CheckBox below. After I enter a Text in the EditText, the Keyboard jumps to the CheckBox. How can I disable that? I want the keyboard to close.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

In the EditText (EditText1), I set

```
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/EditText1"
```

and in java code, I hide the Keyboard when clicking on "Next".